# Image pasting works on localhost but not on server address

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am having some trouble in pasting images in CKEditor.

I am able to paste images when I use localhost. Please refer the image.
[Picture using LocalHost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fhxm.png)

On the other hand, when I use server address instead of localhost, it shows errors. Ctrl+V won't paste the image from clipboard ether. Please refer the image. 
[Picture using server address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ts7X.png)

Note that I am logged into the same server and it only works on IE.

Can someone please point me to the correct direction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I guess, problem is that Internet explorer has different security setting depends on what connection are you using.

> Open Internet Explorer, select the "gear" Tools button , and then select Internet 
>   options. Select the Security tab and customize your security zone
>   settings in these ways:
>
> To change settings for any security zone, select the zone icon, and
>   then move the slider to the security level that you want. To create
>   your own security settings for a zone, select the zone icon, and then
>   select Custom level and choose the settings that you want. To restore
>   all security levels to their original settings, select the Reset all
>   zones to default level button.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17479/windows-internet-explorer-11-change-security-privacy-settings

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried changing settings but, it didn't work. 

Please note that I have same settings for the internet explorer for both the cases i.e. Using server name and Using localhost. Do you think there might some changes in IIS configurations? If yes, what should I try?